# Datetime is formatting differently to only one user when converting to string

Tags: datetime, xamarin.forms, escaping

I need to pass datetime value in the http URL, so that server can send me data based on the changes after datetime.

I'm building the url as follows:

```
public static string AddUrlParams(string api, Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
    {
        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(api);
        if (parameters != null && parameters.Count > 0)
        {
            var hasFirstParam = api.Contains("?");
            foreach (var parameter in parameters)
            {
                var format = hasFirstParam ? "&{0}={1}" : "?{0}={1}";
                stringBuilder.AppendFormat(format, Uri.EscapeDataString(parameter.Key),
                    Uri.EscapeDataString(parameter.Value.ToString()));
                hasFirstParam = true;
            }
        }
        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

one of the parameter in this is Datetime.

For one of my user Datetime.Now.ToString() values is getting as 09/17/2019 05:05:17 a.m.(which causing problem when decoding the url on server side) where as for all other users including myself it's value is 09/17/2019 05:05:17 AM.

Any reason why it is happening for only one particular user?

Comment: either one use has their locale set differently, or their device is just weird.  In either case you should not rely on the default ToString() because it will vary by locale.  Provide a Format string so that the date is always in a consistent format

Comment: yes it could be. I'm changing the code to make it consistent but was curious to know the reason

Comment: Well, what Jason said is pretty much the reason if you ask me!

Comment: Is it possible for locale to change randomly on single device?

Comment: because from my user logs I see different time formats in two different times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by [Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57983344/datetime-is-formatting-differently-to-only-one-user-when-converting-to-string#comment102375806_57983344) in the comments: `ToString` will format the date differently based on the locale set on the computer it's running.

My recommendation would be to use the `o` format when formatting dates which will return an ISO8601 compliant string representation of the `DateTime`. `DateTime` knows how to parse that format natively.

Docs: [click](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime_ToString_System_String_)

To handle this in your loop, you could do something like this:

```
stringBuilder.AppendFormat(
    format,
    Uri.EscapeDataString(parameter.Key),
    Uri.EscapeDataString(parameter.Value is DateTime
        ? parameter.Value.ToString("o")
        : parameter.Value.ToString()));
```